Why am I getting error 404 when I try to call an api using query ID?
I am using this api call to retrieve a list of flat workitems:
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=7.1-preview.2
I was able to get the list, so now I am trying to use this api call so I can retrieve the workitemrelations:
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql/{id}?api-version=7.1-preview.2
I was using the id that I get from my result in the post api call, say in this example is 300.

But I am getting error 404.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>The controller for path &#39;/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql/300&#39; was not found or
        does not implement IController.</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
            height: 100%;
        }

Any idea how to fix this? Thank you
I also tried using this api call, but I still having error 404, but without that html result.
HEAD https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql/{id}?api-version=7.1-preview.2

Hi @user22063307, Have you got a chance to check my answer below to use different API requests to get WIT and revisions? Hope the it can solve your issue. Thx.

We can use this API to get individual WIT information in latest revision.
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=7.1-preview.3

We can use another API to get the information in all revisions for a single workitem.
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/revisions?api-version=7.1-preview.3

